# Disabled button with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this code ([doc](http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event)) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <title>123</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />

</head> 

<body> 

<form>
  <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Comment" maxlength="140" value="">
  <div id="charactersLeft"></div>
  <input type="submit" id="commentButton" data-icon="edit" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-theme="b" value="Send" disabled="disabled">
</form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://zurb.com/playground/javascripts/plugins/jquery.textchange.min.js"></script>

<script>


$(document).ready(function(){

$('#comment').bind('hastext', function () {
  $('#commentButton').removeAttr('disabled');
});

$('#comment').bind('notext', function () {
  $('#commentButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

$('#comment').bind('textchange', function (event, previousText) {
  $('#charactersLeft').html( 140 - parseInt($(this).val().length) );
});

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I deleted css, this works.

In Chrome console:

```
$('#commentButton');

<input type="submit" id="commentButton" data-icon="edit" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" value="Отправить" disabled="disabled" class="ui-btn-hidden" data-disabled="true">
```

Its very strange, because in html I have not got `class="ui-btn-hidden"`. So, I can make some changes in `<script>`:

```
$('#comment').bind('hastext', function () {
  $('#commentButton').removeClass('ui-btn-hidden').removeAttr('disabled');

});
```

And then apears +1 button! Looks like "styles conflict", because without css everything works!

How to fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle for this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kfDHh/ try write something in the form, then delete css and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use jQuery Mobile **[button widget methods](http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/#method-disable)** to enable/disable buttons

```
$('#comment').bind('hastext', function () {
  $('#commentButton').button('enable');
});

$('#comment').bind('notext', function () {
  $('#commentButton').button('disable');
});
```

Comment: Works here http://jsfiddle.net/kfDHh/2/. From the docs: "jQuery Mobile automatically converts any button or input element with a type of submit, reset, or button into a custom styled button"